# Ripple Data API vs Ripple RPC

Tags: ripple, ripple-api

I need to write a program that monitors the transactions that sent to me.
My approach is to periodically (like every 2 minutes) call the Ripple public api to get transactions for my account.  But on the developer doc, I find two way to achieve this:

1. [Ripple Data API](https://developers.ripple.com/data-api.html#get-account-transaction-history) . 
   example:

> https://data.ripple.com/v2/accounts/rf1BiGeXwwQoi8Z2ueFYTEXSwuJYfV2Jpn/transactions?type=Payment&result=tesSUCCESS&limit=3

2. [WebSocket/Json-RPC API](https://developers.ripple.com/account_tx.html). send to `s2.ripple.com:443`
   with websocket or http.  example:

> {   "id": 1,   "command": "account_tx",
>   "account": 
>   "r9cZA1mLK5R5Am25ArfXFmqgNwjZgnfk59",
>   "ledger_index_min": -1,
>   "ledger_index_max": -1,
>   "binary": false,   "count": false,
>   "limit": 10,   "forward": false }

I didn't check carefully, but they seem to have same response(with different format).

My question is :

1. are they equivalent?
2. which one should be preferred or which one is recommended by ripple?

Comment: They provide the same data. The data API is a high reliability service provided by Ripple. The websocket API is a less reliable service anyone running the XRP Ledger software can provide. The websocket APi is a bit harder to use because you have to carefully track which ledgers you've searched over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both solutions. Api is based on Json-RPC. Its app for getting transactions on address. You can change it for your needs.

`const RippleAPI = require('ripple-lib').RippleAPI;
var test_server = 'wss://s2.ripple.com';
const api = new RippleAPI({
    server: test_server // Public rippled server
});
api.connect().then(() => {
    /* begin custom code ------------------------------------ */
    const myAddress = 'rf1BiGeXwwQoi8Z2ueFYTEXSwuJYfV2Jpn';
    console.log('getting account info for', myAddress);
    return api.getTransactions(myAddress);
}).then(info => {
    console.log(info);
    /* end custom code -------------------------------------- */
}).then(() => {
    return api.disconnect();
}).then(() => {
    console.log('done and disconnected.');
}).catch(console.error);`

Good luck)